# How do I allow users to delete Google Analytics data for GDPR compliance?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, gdpr

I'm in the process of making my website GDPR compliant and one of the requirements of GDPR is that users have the ability to delete data. After a user agrees to allow GA, Is there a way for users to delete Google Analytics data?

Comment: The analytics data does not identify them, so I don't believe that you are required to delete that.  Consider a bill in medical practice.  They can not delete the bill for tax  and medical reasons. All they can do is, to delete the contact information.  And in some countries, maybe they can also munge the name so it's not recognisable.

Answer (score 1):

This code expires the cookie ... https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/cookies

```
gtag('config', 'TAG_ID', {
  cookie_update: false
});
```

However if they have agreed to allow you to see that an un-named somebody viewed a page. How does the EU plan for that person who may have seen the report that an un-named somebody viewed a page to no longer have seen it?

An since the user is un-named, how does anybody know what page they saw that should now be un-seen?

You can turn off recording page views ... https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/privacy

```
gtag('set', { 'send_page_view': false });
```

... but not exactly un-see a report that may have been emailed to you last week.

Google is going to need to talk to the EU.